# Remove internal faces from mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm using Blender to create game assets. I'd like to remove internal (unseen) faces prior to export to help optimize my assets. There are too many faces to do this manually in an efficient manner. I've tried the 3D-Print addon, selecting interior faces and haven't had any luck. Simple example is below.

I have tried union boolean - which will get rid of the internal face, but will introduce new faces (resulting in more polys overall) as well as n-gons. I just want to remove the internal face without introducing new faces or n-gons.

Anyone know how I can remove these internal faces efficiently?

[image: mesh]

Comment: Hello, why not use Boolean? il will only create 2 faces on the junction face